# List View Web Part not allowing Current View to be altered

Tags: web-part, list-view, view, wiki-pages

On SharePoint 2010, if I give a user Full Control rights to a wiki page, they can alter the contents of the page and add List View Web Parts. They can then edit most of the features of the Web Part, but the 'Current View' link does not appear for them to click on and then customise the view; they are restricted to only choosing from the from views inside the list itself.

What permissions issue prevents that Current View link from appearing to users? Do they need Design or Full Control access to some other part of the site that controls the appearance of the List View and other Web Parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify list views user will also need manage lists (part of Design permission level) permission to the list to which the List View web part belongs. User can just have contribute premission level to the wiki page instead of full control.